# passenger-spawn-server load error

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, passenger, redmine

I have been struggling for hours now and can not find an appropriate answer on the internet.
I have tried to upgrade ruby1.8 to 1.9.3 but with no luck.
Ruby 1.9.3 is installed, but my rails app (redmine) won't start anymore.

This is the error:

```
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server (LoadError)
[ pid=30103 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2013-01-10 21:49:06.819 ]:
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/usr/share/redmine': Could not read from the spawn server: Connection reset by peer (104)
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

Really, I'm stuck on this, any help is appreciated!

-Brian